# bq command line tool momentarily hangs eating memory with --format=none

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm running a BigQuery query using bq that selects a subset of rows from one table into a destination table.

Our command looks like:

```
bq --format=none query --destination_table=dpm_legacy.unique_test [query]
```

On the command line I get:

```
Waiting on job_cda83335e0a4416ea9d4a2a0262d1ec7 ... (0s) Current status: RUNNING
Waiting on job_cda83335e0a4416ea9d4a2a0262d1ec7 ... (10s) Current status: DONE
```

But then the process hangs for awhile and it's CPU and memory usage begin to creep up until it finally exists with no output.

Empirically, it seems like the amount of time the tool hangs is directly proportional to how large the destination table is so is it possible that even with the --format=none flag it is still returning data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bq does try to read the whole table on reply, even if the format is set to none. One way to prevent this is to use --nosync which will exit immediately and not wait for the query to complete. I'm in the process of adding a --max_rows flag that will allow you to specify how many rows you want in the result (so if you want none you can just specify 0).

Comment: FYI -- I just submitted the fix for this, but you'll need to wait until the next release of bq.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! Is it checked in at http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools ? Might give it a go building from source.

Comment: It isn't checked in to the public repository, but the diff is tiny: (your line numbers may not match because of the reformatting we do)
@@ -965,8 +965,12 @@
+    flags.DEFINE_integer(
+        'max_rows', 100,
+        'How many rows to return in the result.',
+        flag_values=fv)
@@ -990,9 +994,10 @@
-      _PrintTable(client, job['configuration']['query']['destinationTable'])
+      _PrintTable(client, job['configuration']['query']['destinationTable'],
+                  max_rows=FLAGS.max_rows)